# Can I put an inner tube on my space-saver spare wheel/donut?

Tags: spare-tire, donut

My Space-Saver spare wheel (doughnut or mini-spare) no longer holds air so I am thinking about putting an inner tube in it.

Can I do this?

Comment: Hi, Welcome to mechanics.SE :) What size is the doughnut? How old is it? Does it have a puncture or damage? Has the tyre been used?

Answer (score 1):

Not likely, where you going to but the valve for the inner tube? Also why would you depend your life and 3-4k pounds of metal on something that wasn't designed to do so? Go get a $5 spare from the junker if your trying to save money